# R: Package removed from CRAN

Tags: r, cran

The package 'MCDA' is removed from CRAN. Looks like it happened because some 'issues were not solved' but this is confusing still. On the CRAN repository website it reads:

*Package ‘MCDA’ was removed from the CRAN repository.*

*Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.*

*Archived on 2023-05-25 as issues were not corrected in time.*

*A summary of the most recent check results can be obtained from the check results archive.*

*Please use the canonical form https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=MCDA to link to this page.*

I tried to install it this way, but it did not work.

```
remotes::install_version("MCDA", version="0.0.24")
```

Does anyone know how can I get that package back to my R?

Comment: What exactly did not work when using install_version? Did you get an error of some kind? What exactly was the error?

Comment: ```Error in library(MCDA) : there is no package called ‘MCDA’``` This is what appeared. So the downloading didn't work.

Comment: What was the output of `remotes::install_version("MCDA", version="0.0.24")`? It sounds like there must have been an error there so the library was not installed properly. What version of R are you using? What OS are you using? The package was removed because it didn't work on current systems any more. You'll likely have to do some work around depending on your current system. Make sure to check the error message for the things that need to be fixed.